# Where is the way to pull out requests from a collection?

Tags: postman

Update:  I see that the issue was I had hidden the left sidebar which has all these features.

So just imported a huge collection for postman. Import worked fine. Now what I was expecting is that I could just easily pull out an individual request from the collection and inspect it like any other. I also expect that I can create a request using one in the collection as a template.   There must be a way to easily share groups of requests and examine them like others. Inside the collection runner is the only place I am seeing the individual requests. I mean New (Does not allow it to be selected), Import (Already Done That), Collection Runner.  So where is the way to pull out the request? Actually I went ahead and ran the collection with just one request by deselecting all except the one. But the way it is inspected is looks much different. And I want to run this request as all the others are run and inspect it just like the others. I mean this should be the most intuitive thing.

Where is the option here to use one of the requests from a collection?
   This is right after clicking new
[image]

So I decide I want to create a basic one. Now what?

[image]

What indicates the collections selected or available during creation of a request?

So what I can't find is:

1) A easy way to select a collection for use application wide.
2) A easy way to select an individual request from the collection
   and run it individually.

[image]
3) An easy way to just open a collection
   One that is not only collection running. Maybe editing or using one of the items as a template for another request. Also when I click on the left hand side of a request I see a menu but nothing at all comes up. I mean collections of requests should not be just for running in collection runner.

This is the main issue. Beyond that what about editing the requests from a collection?

Comment: Is this an actual question or just a list of items that you find confusing? This isn't really the place to list out a bunch of opinions as no one can really do anything about that here, only Postman can change these things in Postman. I would suggest that you get these thoughts down as a list of actionable improvements and submit a feature request via the Github tracker. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support

Comment: Also, you just need to select _any_ request in the collection on the left side, to see it and interact with it on the main view. As you haven't giving any sort of visual explanation about what you're doing and what you have in front of you its hard to know where you're problem lies. Not sure why you went straight to the runner.

Comment: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7277

Comment: select on the left side of what? The collection runner?

Comment: Your 'question' is a wall of text, break it up into helpful paragraphs and add images to explain what _you_ can see. No one here can see what you have in front of you so explaining it better is key here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a single request from the imported Collection can be down like this:

- Select the `Collections` Tab (If you're not on it already)
- Expand the `Collection`
- Select the `Request` you want to use
- Hit `Send` to use the request

[image: Single Request]

There are a number of ways to use any `Request` as a template for other Collections. You could make a copy of the whole `Collection` and rename it or if you just wanted a single `Request` in a new `Collection` you can do the following:

- On the `Request` select **...**
- Select `Duplicate` to make a copy of the `Request`
- Select the `Save As` option

From here you can rename the Request and also create a new `Collection` containing that request.

[image: Duplicate]

There are a lot of things that you can do with the app, maybe either looking through the learning centre:

https://learning.getpostman.com/

Or using the in-app `Bootcamp` will help you understand the app more and what it can offer you:

[image]

Comment: Ok, I see what happened now. I lost the left sidebar. I dont recall doing this but I must have clicked clicked at some point and then forgotten. Maybe only suggestion then is that there be be some view menu at the top or somewhere I really was not looking down at the bottom for this option. The reason I forgot this is because I use the product intermittently and so I did not remember this action.

Comment: I have modified my request to be just about menu access:https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7278 and closed the other issue.